# Recording Data from Callbacks using ExtAudioFileWrite

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm currently recording stereo audio from the microphone of the iPhone and I have to record the data from the callbacks for analysis.

Currently my AudioStreamBasicDescription format is

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription format;
format.mSampleRate          = 0;
format.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
format.mFormatFlags         = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
format.mFramesPerPacket     = 1;
format.mChannelsPerFrame    = 2;
format.mBitsPerChannel      = 32;
format.mBytesPerPacket      = 4;
format.mBytesPerFrame       = 4;
```

and the buffer list I render data into is

```
inputBufferList->mNumberBuffers = NUMCHANNELS;
for (size_t n = 0; n < NUMCHANNELS; n++) {
    inputBufferList->mBuffers[n].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * sizeof(float);
    inputBufferList->mBuffers[n].mNumberChannels = 1;
    inputBufferList->mBuffers[n].mData = malloc(inputBufferList->mBuffers[n].mDataByteSize);
}
```

When I try to write this data into the ExtAudioFileWrite, it gives an error and it was said that the format is wrong. Is there any tutorial on how to write stereo audio using ExtAudioFileWrite?

Edit:

Here is how I'm setting it up

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* destinationFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@/testrecording.wav", documentsDirectory];

CFURLRef destinationURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)destinationFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

OSStatus status;

ExtAudioFileRef cfref;

status = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL, kAudioFileWAVEType,
                                   &format, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                   &cfref);
```

The status shows an exception in this

Comment: Can you show how you're setting up and calling the `ExtAudioFile`?

Comment: I updated the question @RhythmicFistman

Comment: So `ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL` is failing? What status does it return?

Comment: OSStatus 1718449215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1718449215 is `kAudioConverterErr_FormatNotSupported` ('fmt?'), so I'm guessing that WAVE might not support float LPCM. You could try changing to `kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger` or switching file format, e.g. `kAudioFileM4AType`, `kAudioFileCAFType`, or (maybe?) `kAudioFileAIFFType`.

Don't forget to update format sizes for the former, and filename extension for the latter.

Comment: I don't mind using signed integer LPCM, but stereo recording is necessary. What would be the ASBD setting for that? And would I have to change my buffer list as well?

Comment: Interleaved is probably easiest. Remove `kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved` and the loop when setting up the buffer list.

Comment: So I went ahead and used CAF and did all that you asked i.e. keep the type just Signed Integer. It works fine now. Thank you so much.